# Cant call web service from jsonp

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, jsonp

I cannot seem to be able to hit my webmethod with my jsonp call... what am i doing wrong? instead i get the following as an error.. See methods bellow

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://askia.service.local/AskiaService.asmx/Login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://askia.web.local' is therefore not allowed access.

**Web service call**

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public User Login(string username, string password)
    {
        User userLoggedIn;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            throw new Exception("username or/and password is not supplied");
        }

        try
        {
            var dataAccess = new DataAccess(ConnectionString);
            userLoggedIn = new User(dataAccess.Login(username, password));
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw exception;
        }

        return userLoggedIn;
    }
```

**JsonP**

```
function AddTaskList(taskListTitle) {
    var jsonDataObject = JSON.stringify({
        'username': 'username',
        'password': 'password'
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://askia.service.local/AskiaService.asmx/Login",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: jsonDataObject,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
    alert('task list added');
}
```

Comment: is the data type really a `jsonp`? I seriously doubt that..change it to `json` and see?

Comment: i have updated my code, now i get this error. XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://askia.service.local/AskiaService.asmx/Login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://askia.web.local' is therefore not allowed access. @AkashRajbanshi

Comment: did you enable Cors?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try change

```
dataType: "json",
```

to

```
dataType: "jsonp",
```